# How to load a picture from File system and preview it using Jquery

Tags: jquery, image

Using Input file control in a Add page(add.aspx) to preview(using Jquery) and to upload the image(works perfectly).

While using different url parameters ,the Add Page(add.aspx) is meant to load the image from the uploaded the file path and preview it on load.

I'm stuck and don't know how to achieve it? any help will be much appreciated!!

If I use the same input:file to load the picture dynamically using jquery code it will be much easier because I'm loading a load of images in the page?

**Jquery code to preview**

```
 $(function () {
        // Create the close button
        var closebtn = $('<button/>', {
            type: "button",
            text: 'x',
            id: 'close-preview',
            style: 'font-size: initial;',
        });
        closebtn.attr("class", "close pull-right");
        // Set the popover default content
        $('#div_email_logo').popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            html: true,
            title: "<strong>Preview</strong>" + $(closebtn)[0].outerHTML,
            content: "There's no image",
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
        // Clear event
        $('#btn_email_logo').click(function () {
            $('#div_email_logo').attr("data-content", "").popover('hide');
            $('#txb_email_logo').val("");
            $('#btn_email_logo').hide();
            $('#div_email_logo_preview input:file').val("");
            $("#sp_email_logo").text("Browse");
        });
        // Create the preview image
        $("#div_email_logo_preview input:file").change(function () {
            var img = $('<img/>', {
                id: 'dynamic',
                width: 250,
                height: 200
            });
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Set preview image into the popover data-content
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("#sp_email_logo").text("Change");
                $("#btn_email_logo").show();
                $("#txb_email_logo").val(file.name);
                img.attr('src', e.target.result);
                $("#div_email_logo").attr("data-content", $(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

 <div class=" image-preview form-group  col-lg-6" id="div_email_logo" style="display: table">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" runat="server" disabled="disabled" placeholder="email Logo" id="txb_email_logo">
                                <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" id="btn_email_logo" style="display: none;">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Clear
                                    </button>
                                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input" id="div_email_logo_preview">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                        <span class="image-preview-input-title" id="sp_email_logo">Browse</span>
                                        <%--  <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview" />--%>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="uplemail_Logo" runat="server" class="image-logo" err="required" filetype="image" accept=".jpg , .gif ,.png ,.jpeg" required="True" />
                                        <!-- rename it -->
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
```

**Snapshot of image preview**
[image: Add logo works fine]

All the examples are from the page when adding the picture? I would like to use the same page to load the uploaded image from file system? preferably same controls and slight tweaks in code?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want this to be a solely front end solution?

Comment: front end will be preferred bcoz I'm using jquery to preview it, I don't mind c#/vb.net solution at the moment.

Comment: This article should sort you out: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Also, note that reading local file data on IE is poorly supported...

Comment: Any server side solution would be repetitive in my opinion. If you're going to send the file to you server (using ajax for example) purely for the sake of showing a preview, you may as well just upload the file.

Comment: IE? Is there is solution which works fine over all platform? Also in my scenario when the page loads the existing file uploaded in the filesystem should be ready to preview like I showed in the snapshot above and then the user can clear or change the image after that?

Comment: It works, but only form IE10 if I remember correctly. These solutions mentioned in the article are cross browser, when supported. Let's be honest, the preview is not a necessity, it's a nicety!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Achieved it,

Now I can load the picture and preview it when the page loads

Did some tweaks in the code

**Here is the working code**

**Jquery**

```
// Create the close button
            var closebtn = $('<button/>', {
                type: "button",
                text: 'x',
                id: 'print-close-preview',
                style: 'font-size: initial;',
            });
            closebtn.attr("class", "close pull-right");
            // Set the popover default content
            $('#div_print_logo').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                html: true,
                title: "<strong>Preview</strong>" + $(closebtn)[0].outerHTML,
                content: "There's no image",
                placement: 'bottom'
            });
            // Clear event
            $('#btn_print_logo').click(function () {
                $('#div_print_logo').attr("data-content", "").popover('hide');
                $('#txb_print_logo').val("");
                $('#btn_print_logo').hide();
                $('#div_print_logo_preview input:file').val("");
                $("#sp_print_logo").text("Browse");
            });
            // Create the preview image
            $("#div_print_logo_preview input:file").change(function () {
                var img = $('<img/>', {
                    id: 'dynamic',
                    width: 250,
                    height: 200
                });
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                // Set preview image into the popover data-content
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $("#sp_print_logo").text("Change");
                    $("#btn_print_logo").show();
                    $("#txb_print_logo").val(file.name);
                    img.attr('src', e.target.result);
                    $("#div_print_logo").attr("data-content", $(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
                }
// New tweaks
                if (file) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                else {
                    $("#sp_print_logo").text("Change");
                    $("#btn_print_logo").show();
                    var src = $('#<%= imgPrintLogo.ClientID%>').attr("src");
                    img.attr('src', src);
                    $("#div_print_logo").attr("data-content", $(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
                }
            });
```

**Aspx**

```
div class=" image-preview form-group  col-lg-6" id="div_email_logo" style="display: table">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" runat="server" disabled="disabled" placeholder="email Logo" id="txb_email_logo">
                                <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" id="btn_email_logo" style="display: none;">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Clear
                                    </button>
                                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input" id="div_email_logo_preview">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                        <span class="image-preview-input-title" id="sp_email_logo">Browse</span>

                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="uplemail_Logo" runat="server" class="image-logo" err="required" filetype="image" accept=".jpg , .gif ,.png ,.jpeg" required="True" />
 <%-- Added Tweaks--%>
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" Width="250" height="200" style="display: none;"/>
                                        <!-- rename it -->
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
```

Updated the url value for Image(imgLogo) in serverside(c#) in page load.

Comment: its great when we are able to resolve our own problems.

Comment: true mate, it is a pleasant feeling